# Get webSQL data from loop output

Tags: jquery, database, web-sql

I am looping through my database rows and outputting a list of these items.

However, I need some context.

When I click a row, I'd like to show all associated data (name, ID, etc, etc). I can assign a data attribute to my row, and this works for the name, but not everything else.

```
function displayResults( tx, results ){

    var row = "";
    for(var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
        row = results.rows.item(i);
        currentID = row.myID;
        currentName = row.name;

        var wrapper = $('<div class="client-row" data-name="'+ currentID +'" />').appendTo('.client-list');
        wrapper.append ('<div class="client-name" >' + currentName + '</div>');

        $('.client-row').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newID = $( this ).attr( "data-name" );
            $(".current-client").text(results.rows[newID].name);
            $(".indiv-client").show();
        });
    }
}
```

So, for example, I also need `row.sketch` but when clicking on the row, have no context as to where to look for this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are looking for, you need an HTML solution only.

You can create a data tag for each column in the row and store it's value in that tag, similar to your data-name tag.

If you don't know the names of all the columns you can iterate through the columns to build all the tags"

```
var temp='';
for (var c in row) {
  temp+= 'data-' + c + '="' + row[c] + '"';
}
var wrapper = $('<div class="client-row"'+ temp +' />').appendTo('.client-list');
```